# A short proof of this? $\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\psi(x)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$ extended to all $\mathbb{R}$ continuously. I know $\psi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ but I am looking for a short proof of this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}x=\int_0^1\phi'(tx)\,dt$$
and this can be differentiated (repeatedly) under the integral sign.

Comment: Nice trick. @NombreFalso123  For justification purposes, look up the wikipedia page on Leibnez' Integral Rule